# How do I override all theme pagination throughout a site?

Tags: pagination

I have a site that lists vehices for sale.  One page is a stocklist which shows 6 entries per page as standard.  The news page also has this function.

Is there a simple way of overriding all pagination code to display all posts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pre_get_posts` to override the `posts_per_page` setting

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && !$q->is_singular() // Do not target singular posts
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
});
```